# Authenticate session between frontend microservice and Spring Cloud Gateway setup as OAuth2 Client (oauth2login)

Tags: spring-security-oauth2, spring-cloud-gateway

I'm currently trying to implement a Spring Cloud API Gateway which acts as an OAuth2 client implementing Spring Security's oauth2Login() to authenticate against a third party OpenID Connect auth provider. The gateway then relays tokens to any API microservices sitting behind it (which are set up as Spring OAuth2 resource servers). In front of the gateway will be a frontend microservice. The intention being the frontend makes API requests via the gateway, gateway handles login / oauth redirects as well as the token relay.

The oauth2Login() works fine when directly connecting to the gateway, the session authenticates, session cookie is set and the gateway relays tokens to the microservices successfully.

### The issue I am facing:

From the frontend microservice, when issuing a request to an API via the gateway the auth flow will start, I'm redirected to the OIDC login page and I provide the credentials, however on the redirect back to the gateway I'm hitting an `OAuth2AuthorizationException` "authorization_request_not_found" and am presented with an "Invalid Credentials" error page.

Prior to the redirect to the OIDC server, I can see the SESSION cookie is being set in [CookieWebSessionIdResolver#setSessionId](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-framework/blob/271a9097ac49c68df35f8ebbd50fe40ba73d290c/spring-web/src/main/java/org/springframework/web/server/session/CookieWebSessionIdResolver.java#L109) eg.

```
"SESSION=<session-id>; Path=/; Domain=mydomain.com; Secure; HttpOnly; SameSite=Lax"
```

It doesn't look like the session cookie is being set though; after I'm redirected back to the gateway  [WebSessionOAuth2ServerAuthorizationRequestRepository#removeAuthorizationRequest](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-security/blob/3f2057364eb04ad68d8c02fd9a003519f40bc94e/oauth2/oauth2-client/src/main/java/org/springframework/security/oauth2/client/web/server/WebSessionOAuth2ServerAuthorizationRequestRepository.java#L75) fails to find the authorization request on the current session. Inspecting the logs actually shows that a new WebSession is being created, presumably because the session cookie never gets set. I can see the prior session is still in the session store though, along with the related authorization request.

I'm unsure if this is possibly a cors issue or cookie issue or something else. Should it be possible to make a simple API get request from my frontend via the gateway and expect the auth flow to complete successfully?

### The setup:

Each of my services shares the same subdomain eg.

```
frontend.mydomain.com:3000
gateway.mydomain.com:8443
backend-service.mydomain.com:8444
```

My Spring Cloud Gateway app has the following configuration:

```yaml
server:
  port: 8443
spring:
  application:
    name: gateway
  cloud:
    gateway:
      default-filters:
        - TokenRelay=
        - RemoveRequestHeader=Cookie
      routes:
        - id: api-service
          uri: https://microservice.mydomain.com/api
          predicates:
            - Path=/api/**
  security:
    oauth2:
      client:
        provider:
          oidc:
            authorization-uri: https://oidcserver/services/oauth2/authorize
            issuer-uri: https://oidcserver
            user-name-attribute: preferred_username
        registration:
          oidc:
            client-id: ${CLIENT_ID}
            client-secret: ${CLIENT_SECRET}
            scope: openid, refresh_token
```

While testing, I've written the following security config for the gateway:

```java
@EnableWebFluxSecurity
@EnableReactiveMethodSecurity
public class SecurityConfig {

    @Bean
    public SecurityWebFilterChain securityWebFilterChain(ServerHttpSecurity serverHttpSecurity, ReactiveClientRegistrationRepository clientRegistrationRepository) {
        return serverHttpSecurity
                .csrf().disable()
                .cors().and()
                .authorizeExchange().anyExchange().authenticated().and()
                .logout().logoutSuccessHandler(new OidcClientInitiatedServerLogoutSuccessHandler(clientRegistrationRepository)).and()
                .httpBasic().disable()
                .formLogin().disable()
                .oauth2Login().and()
                .build();
    }

    @Bean
    public CorsWebFilter corsWebFilter() {
        CorsConfiguration configuration = new CorsConfiguration();
        configuration.setAllowedOriginPatterns(List.of("https://*.mydomain.com"));
        configuration.setAllowedMethods(List.of("PUT", "POST", "GET", "DELETE", "OPTIONS"));
        configuration.setExposedHeaders(List.of("*"));
        configuration.setAllowedHeaders(List.of("*"));
        configuration.setAllowCredentials(true);
        UrlBasedCorsConfigurationSource source = new UrlBasedCorsConfigurationSource();
        source.registerCorsConfiguration("/**", configuration);

        return new CorsWebFilter(source);
    }
}
```

Also for testing, I've set up a /userinfo endpoint on the gateway itself

```java
@RestController
public class UserController {

    @GetMapping("/userinfo")
    public ResponseEntity<Object> getUserInfo(@AuthenticationPrincipal(expression = "userInfo") OidcUserInfo userInfo) {
        return ResponseEntity.ok(userInfo == null ? "Anonymous" : userInfo);
    }
}
```

On the frontend, I've setup a simple express.js server that makes a get request to the /userinfo endpoint on the gateway

```js
const express = require('express')
const axios = require('axios')
const https = require('https')
const fs = require('fs')

const app = express()
const port = 3000

app.get('/userinfo', (req, res) => {
    process.env['NODE_TLS_REJECT_UNAUTHORIZED'] = 0
    axios.get('https://gateway.mydomain.com:8443/userinfo', {
        headers: {
            withCredentials: true
        }
    }).then(response => {
        console.log(response)
    }).catch(error => {
        console.log(error)
    })
})

https.createServer({
    key: fs.readFileSync('selfsigned.key'),
    cert: fs.readFileSync('selfsigned.cert')
}, app)
.listen(port, () => {
    console.log('https://frontend.mydomain.com:3000')
})
```

Spring versions I'm running:

Spring Boot 2.4.2 & Spring Cloud 2020.0.0

Comment: Did you get this running? I'm facing a similar problem but couldn't come up with a solution so far...

Comment: Unfortunately not, we moved towards a more typical setup with an oAuth2Client on the front end, so this remained unresolved.